# All Combinations of Array, Stopping at Three Levels C#

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I am trying to loop through an array and get every possible combination, but I need it to stop after three levels. For example:

```
String[] arr = ["Service1", "Service2", "Service3", "Service4"];
```

It is possible for there to be more than four in the array, but from this example I would like to be able to generate the following combinations:

```
Service1, Service2, Serivce3
Service1, Service2, Serivce4
Service1, Service3, Serivce2
Service1, Service3, Serivce4
Service1, Service4, Serivce2
Service1, Service4, Serivce3

Service2, Service1, Serivce3
Service2, Service1, Serivce4
Service2, Service3, Serivce1
Service2, Service3, Serivce4
Service2, Service4, Serivce3
Service2, Service4, Serivce1

Service3, Service1, Serivce2
Service3, Service1, Serivce4
Service3, Service2, Serivce1
Service3, Service2, Serivce4
Service3, Service4, Serivce2
Service3, Service4, Serivce1

Service4, Service2, Serivce3
Service4, Service2, Serivce1
Service4, Service3, Serivce2
Service4, Service3, Serivce1
Service4, Service1, Serivce2
Service4, Service1, Serivce3
```

So far what I have tried and researched does not give me these results and I would greatly appreciate any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: Since, apparently, order matters (`Service3, Service4, Service2` and `Service4, Service2, Serivce3` are separate results), then what you're referring to here is normally referred to a *Permutations*, rather than *Combinations* (combinations are similar to permutations but order doesn't matter). You may have better luck googling using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take [this library from CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) and use the Combination class like in this example:

```
char[] inputSet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

var combinations = new Combinations<char>(inputSet, 3);
var cformat = "Combinations of {{A B C D}} choose 3: size = {0}";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cformat, combinations.Count));

foreach(var combination in combinations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", combination);
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, at least the way OP asked it. It will print out `{A B C}, {A B D}, {A C D},
{B C D}`, i.e. 4 choose 3 = 4 results. Clearly the order is important here, as OP posted a list of 24 results. You should have used the `Variations` class instead (in the section right below the code you copy/pasted).

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I wrote a program yesterday as a coding challenge that  [finds all permutations of a string with a given length.](https://github.com/christopher-helling/Projects/blob/master/Misc/permutations-of-length-k.cs) Note that I remove duplicates, e.g. "pop" has 3! = 6 letter arrangements, but the 'p' is repeated twice and indistinguishable, hence 3!/2 = 3 (i.e. "opp", "pop", "ppo").

```
static HashSet<string> outputSet = new HashSet<string>();

        // this function will find all the strings of length k you can make from a set of letters N
        // e.g. "pop" --> pop, ppo, opp
        static void permuteSetLength(string prefix, string suffix, int length)
        {
            if (length == 0)
            {
                outputSet.Add(prefix);
                return;
            }

            // use dictionary to remove duplicate prefixes, to avoid permuting the same thing again
            Dictionary<string, string> newPrefixesAndSuffixes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            // otherwise, calculate our new prefixes by adding each letter of suffix to the prefix, and decrementing length by 1
            for (int i = 0; i < suffix.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!newPrefixesAndSuffixes.ContainsKey(prefix + suffix[i])) // new key
                {
                    // remove ith character from suffix and add it to prefix 
                    permuteSetLength(prefix + suffix[i], suffix.Substring(0,i) + suffix.Substring(i+1), length - 1);
                }

            }
        }
```

This should be a good starting point for you. I'm sure you can see the connection between finding the permutations of a string (i.e. character array) and the permutations of a string array.

Call the code like so:

```
permuteSetLength("", "abcd", 3);
string[] outputArray = new string[outputSet.Count];
outputSet.CopyTo(outputArray);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", outputArray));
```

It prints out the following:

> abc, abd, acb, acd, adb, adc, bac, bad, bca, bcd, bda, bdc, cab, cad, cba, cbd, cda, cdb, dab, dac, dba, dbc, dca, dcb

Count of 24, i.e. 4 * 3 * 2 = 24, exactly as expected. It should be easy now to map each character to a string, although I would suggest modifying the method itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
var strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var combinations = (
from s1 in strings
from s2 in strings.Where(s => s != s1)
from s3 in strings.Where(s => s != s2 && s != s1)
select new { s1, s2, s3 }).Distinct();

foreach (var c in combinations)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{c.s1}{c.s2}{c.s3}");
}
```

Probably, code can be a polished a bit more, but it works.

Hope that will help.

Comment: You have an issue with your `Console.WriteLine($"{c.s1}{c.s2}{c.s3}");` line, as that won't compile.

Comment: It depends on which version of c# you're using.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I haven't kept up with the latest C# versions... I still have Visual Studio 2010 at work. :O